# How to Delete Records in a object except Newly created 1000 Records by using Batch Class?

Tags: apex, soql, batch, querylocator

I have a question, how to delete all records except newly created 1000 records(For Eg: in a Account Object i have 11000 records,in that 1000 records are created in this month, now all 10000 records should be delete,except recently created 1000 records.) by using batch class.

```
global class Deletecc implements DataBase.Batchable<sObject>
{
    global DataBase.QueryLocator start(DataBase.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        return DataBase.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id,Name FROM Credit_Card__c LIMIT 1000]);
    }
    global void execute(DataBase.BatchableContext bc,List<Credit_Card__c> ListTli)
    {
        List<Credit_Card__c> ListTarget = new List<Credit_Card__c>();
        //List<Credit_Card__c> ListTarget1000 = new List<Credit_Card__c>();
        for(Credit_Card__c t : ListTli)
        {
            if(t.Name!=null) 
            {
                ListTarget.add(t);
                system.debug('-->>'+ListTarget);
            }
         } 
        if(ListTarget.size()>0)
        {
            delete ListTarget;
        }
    }
    global void finish(DataBase.BatchableContext bc)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to write SOQL for this requirement?

Comment: yes Santanu Boral, l have used LIMIT as my filter,but how to find the count of new records ?

Comment: can you post your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: @SantanuBoral see the code which i have tried,but its a standard delete batch class, i need help in Soql Query

Comment: You don't need to use the `global` modifier...

Comment: Okay @AdrianLarson i will make changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to skip the newest 1000 records, use an `OFFSET` clause. Make sure you add an `ORDER BY` clause as well so that the newest records are those skipped. Since you can't use `OFFSET` in your query locator, you'll have to query down the 1000th record and use its `CreatedDate` in your filter:

```
MyObject__c thresholdRecord = [
    SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1000
];
return Database.getQueryLocator([
    SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c
    WHERE CreatedDate <= :thresholdRecord.CreatedDate
]);
```

Comment: I have used OFFSET But i am Getting  this error: FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: SOQL OFFSET clause is not supported in Batch Apex.

Answer (score 1):

Using trigger or execute anonymous window

```
Datetime d = datetime.now().addmonth(1)
List <account> a = list <account>();
a = [select id,name from account where created date >: d limit1000];
Delete a;
```

Comment: How is this answer even related to the question? This doesn't get you the newest records, and can't ever even return data, since `CreatedDate` is the field's API Name and it will never have a value in the future.